# received run time error 1004 and i dont understand why

Tags: excel, vba

I dont understand why i received run time error 1004 while setting the range. The purpose of this code is to multiply 1000 to the col B. B3 is the header and the data starts at B4.

```
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rngData As Range
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B" & LastRow)     [run time error 1004]
    For Each Cell In rngData
        Cell.Value = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*1000")
    Next Cell
```

Comment: How define `LastRow`? What is data type? How you calculate `LastRow`?

Comment: i have edited my code! But it still didnt work

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Why not just `Cell.Value = Cell.Value * 1000` though?

Comment: i didnt know i can use it. When i tried using evaluate, why does the output gave the same result?

Comment: Try F9 to set a breakpoint on the `Set rngData =` instruction, then hover `LastRow` when the breakpoint is hit or type `?lastrow` in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G). Is it what you're expecting? Is the correct/expected sheet active when the code runs? You're getting the last row off column A, but then getting a range from column B. If `LastRow` is `0` for some reason, then the range address is invalid and that would throw error 1004. `LastRow` could be `0` if you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere and there's no `ActiveSheet`, I guess.

Comment: Noted! Thank you for teaching me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in `LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` This part `Cells(Rows.Count, 1)` detect last row to `Column A` Try below sub.

```
Sub Multiply1000()
Dim rngData As Range, cel As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B" & LastRow)  '[run time error 1004]
    
    For Each cel In rngData
        cel.Value = cel.Value * 1000
    Next cel

Set rngData = Nothing
End Sub
```